# Get file name of download file using download manager in android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

As we know [DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME) is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#sharing-files) form api level 24 and to get the file name of file which downloaded from download manager google are saying access file name using  [ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openFileDescriptor(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String))

Can anyone suggest me how to access filename using [ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openFileDescriptor(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the filename via `openFileDescriptor()`. Since you were the one who requested the download, you already know what the filename is.

Comment: Thanks for answer then what is use of ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor() ?

Comment: @user2534612: To get at the downloaded content. To be honest, I do not know why recommend that, since you already have access to wherever the file is (otherwise, AFAIK, you would not be able to enqueue the download request).

Answer (score -1):

I did not use ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor().

To retrieve the good old absolute path of the downloaded file just :

```
String absolutePath =  Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI))).getPath();
```

And of course :

```
File file = new File(absolutePath);
```